# Keep alive service in android api =< 23

Tags: android, android-service, android-5.0-lollipop

How to keep a service alive using AlarmManager in Android API 23?

I need to update my method every 1 minutes.
This is my service:

```
public class ApplicationService extends Service {

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent paramIntent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Log.d(ApplicationService.class.getName(), "start");
        UpdateUtils updateUtils = UpdateUtils.getInstance(getApplicationContext());

        IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
        intentFilter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_DATE_CHANGED);
        intentFilter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_TIMEZONE_CHANGED);
        intentFilter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_TIME_CHANGED);
        intentFilter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON);
        intentFilter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_TIME_TICK);
        registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceivers(), intentFilter);

        Utils utils = Utils.getInstance(getBaseContext());
        utils.loadApp();
        updateUtils.update(true);
        return START_STICKY;
    }
}
```

Comment: What code have you already tried?

Comment: Have you tried calling startForeground(int, notification)? http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#startForeground(int, android.app.Notification)

Comment: Link the code that uses the AlarmManager..

Answer (score 0):

Sorry couldnt understand your issue, why you need Alarm manager to keep service alive?

Service always runs in background by itself. If killed due to memory constraints, you can ask OS to restart it by defining it as STICKY in onBind() method

---

Update

then you do not want to keep your Service alive. I mean, the way you have stated your query is confusing. What I now understand is, that you want to perform some action after every 'xx' time.

you can do following:
use `setExact()` method of `AlarmManager`. Perform the operation required in receiver's `onReceive()`. As part of the last step in this onReceive(), again use setExact() method.

You can also make use of `setRepeating()` if the execution time is not supposed to be precise.

Comment: In android lollipop services going to sleep on turn off screen

Answer (score 0):

If your concern is when the application is locked have you tried using a wakelock?

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html

Comment: Try using http://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html.

"They operate outside of your application, so you can use them to trigger events or actions even when your app is not running, and even if the device itself is asleep."